# Task process with different form for one user

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, approval-process

Using SharePoint Designer 2010. Is it possible to have a separate form for a specific user in a task process? My requirement is to have one user enter information in the form while the others only click approve or reject. If it's not possible, how could I achieve this? Currently I'm using two task processes in a parallel block but it's proving to have some faults.

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 1):

For SharePoint Designer it may be needed to do everything by hand with hard coding. A more OOB way will be using InfoPath, you can [display a view that is based on a user role](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/display-a-view-that-is-based-on-a-user-role-7a85c374-151f-4a2e-8ea2-63c9fad2c557).

Or you will need to create a data connection to receive the user information and add rules for switching views. Similar thread here:[Change view on Infopath form depending on user permission group](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/241771/change-view-on-infopath-form-depending-on-user-permission-group)